# How can I arrange the input filename and additional arguments when writing an awk script?

Tags: awk

I would like to write an awk script, so that 
I can run the script name directly in bash without writing `awk` as the command name.

How can I arrange the input filename and additional arguments to be specified at command line and passed into the script?

Should the script, say `myscript.awk` start with a shebang:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
```

or

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
```

or no shebang?

How I shall I write the script to handle the command line arguments, so that I can run it like `myscript.awk inputfile arg1 arg2` or `myscript.awk arg1 arg2 inputfile` ?

How should I handle the options to `awk`, such as `-F'\t'`?

Or what are some alternative ways to do it?

Or shall I do it indirectly, by writing a bash script which calls `awk` on my awk program?

Thanks

Comment: Don't name your tool `myscript.awk` if you plan to call it directly rather than via `awk -f myscript.awk`.

Comment: do you mean name it `myscript` without extension `.awk`?

Comment: Yes I do. Tools should be named based on what they DO, not what language they're written in. If you have a tool named "foo" written in shell (or awk or python or perl or ruby or...) and you decide to rewrite it in C, the resultant tool should still be named "foo". From a user POV there should be no visible difference. So don't add ".awk" or ".sh" or any other extension to tool names.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. Does what you advise depends on whether a script contains a shebang?  If I write a script without shebang, so that the script has to be given as an argument to its interpreter, should I name the script with an extension (like .sh, .awk) indicating its interpreter?

Comment: If you're writing a shell script, give it a shebang and do not include a suffix. If you're writing an awk (or other tool) script to be passed to awk as `awk -f script.awk` etc. then do give it a suffix. Again, the name of a tool that you call from the command line should be independent of the language the tool is written in.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use bash to do most of the job, and then invoke awk with all the parameters. That way you have full access to bash builtins and other things.

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$1
var2=$2
separator=$3

awk -F "$separator" -v myvar1="$var1" -v myvar2="$var2" '
    BEGIN {
        print myvar1, myvar2
    }
'
```

Double quotes are good in case your parameters contain spaces (like many filenames).

Comment: Right. AFAIK it is never useful to start a shell script with a shebang to invoke awk as it robs you of the ability to use shell and awk separately, each for what they're best at. Just add a `shift 3` after the first 3 assignments and then `"$@"` after the final `'` so awk sees every non-assignment parameter as a file name: `var1=$1; var2=$2; sep=$3; shift 3;  ... awk 'script' "$@"`. Obviously you can add a call to [getopts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) to make the argument parsing in the shell part more robust.